# Android Studio not working after update 1.3.0

Tags: android, plugins, android-studio, updates

I've been running Android Studio on Windows 7 since January and haven't performed an update until today. I started having a problem last week in which AS caused my computer to crash every time I tried to run my application, so I decided to finally stop ignoring the popup which told me updates were available. After downloading and running the file from the Android site, I'm seeing a plethora of error messages along the lines of:

> Unable to save settings. Failed to save settings. Please restart Android Studio

and

> Cannot load settings from file ' (several different files have been listed) ': content truncated File content will be recreated"

and

> Plugin Error
>   Problems found loading plugins: Plugin "Android Support" was not loaded: required plugin "Gradle" is disabled. Plugin "SDK Updater" was not loaded: required plugin "Gradle" is disabled. Plugin "Android NDK Support" was not loaded: required plugin "Gradle" is disabled. Plugin "Google Cloud Tools For Android Studio" was not loaded: required plugin "Gradle" is disabled. Plugin "Google Cloud Testing" was not loaded: required plugin "Gradle" is disabled. Plugin "Google Services" was not loaded: required plugin "Gradle" is disabled.

All of that might be ignored except for the fact that when opening my existing projects none of the files seem to load, meaning I can't do anything.

So basically I'm worse off now than I was before.

Restarting Android Studio multiple times has not resolved the problem. I also cleared the cache and tried removing the old .AndroidStudio file on the advice of another stackOverflow question, but to no avail. Can anyone help me out on this?

Comment: Have you tried a clean install?

Comment: I was hoping to avoid it for the sake of time, but if I don't get any better answers here that's my next step.

Comment: Performed a clean install and everything seems to be fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a clean install and it worked for me.

Comment: This is what I did and it worked. Other solutions may also be viable.

Answer (score 1):

I got solution for

> Cannot load settings from file ' (several different files have been
>   listed) ': content truncated File content will be recreated"

by just deleting `recentProjects.xml` from `C:\Users\Username\.AndroidStudio1.3\config\options` it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I got a simple solution:
1. go to settings>plugins
2. Check all the boxes at your right(especially the one marked red)
3. Update or install the plugin if required(make sure the red marked texts disappears)
4. Finally restart your studio and you are good to go

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the first error message:

> Unable to save settings. Failed to save settings. Please restart Android Studio

After checking the log files I realised that the file .AndroidStudio1.3/config/inspection wasn't a directory as expected by Studio, but a regular file. After removing it and creating a directory with the same name instead, everything was working fine again.

Answer (score 0):

if you see those errors then just below those errors there is some line in blue color that show INSTALL plugins click on that and it restart your studeo then it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error after i have installed genymotion with plugin but it was not working correctly so i uninstalled it from control panel. but plugin icon was still appearing in android studio.i reinstalled android studio but the error and icon was still there.
The following solution worked for me:

1) File->Settings->plugins;

2) in the plugin panel, check all the plugins except genymotion plugin.click apply.

3) Restart Android Studio and that's it.

Not confirmed about internet because i have tried without internet it was giving error but when i connected to internet it is done.