# Selected directory is not a valid home for JDK Android Studio on MacOs

Tags: java, android

I have been using Java 1.7 until I updated to 1.8.0_60. Now, I can't compile or create a new Android project.

**What happens?** I feel uncertain about Platform Settings->SDKs->Android API 22 Platform with question mark forefront,and I get plugin Error:    Plugin Error
          Problems found loading plugins:

```
      Plugin "SDK Updater" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
      Plugin "Android NDK Support" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
      Plugin "Google Cloud Tools For Android Studio" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
      Plugin "Google Cloud Testing" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
      Plugin "Google Services" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
```

What can i do?

Comment: Go to menu bart Window->Preferences->Android and set the SDK Location to this of your SDK root directory

Comment: I install the Android Studio completely and reinstall it.All will be fine! [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625622/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: Check my solution here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31757260/android-studio-not-working-after-update-1-3-0/32863715#32863715